# Why does the Linpack Benchmark solves two Matrixes (n and n+1)?

Tags: benchmarking

I'm currently testing several Linpack Apps as well as the original Linpack from [netlib.org](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/linpackc).

While most currently available Implementations of the Linpack Benchmark only calculate a give Matrix (e.g. 500x500), the original Linpack was meant to calculate two Matrixes for a given dimension n. n and n+1 (eg. if n is 500 -> then first 500x500 and 501x501) as far as how I understood how these things work.
But why does it calculate the second Matrix with n+1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what I wondered when I produced a version, for PCs (that had low resolution timers in the early days). This was accepted by Netlib in 1996 and can be found there:

http://www.netlib.no/netlib/benchmark/linpack-pc.c

I believe that it was looking for memory address alignment performance issues that must have been important at some time. The following has results for this on PCs and other versions for Windows, Linux and Androids, including Java.

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/linpack%20results.htm

This version is unsuitable for multiprocessors but users are allowed to implement their own linear equation solver. See:

http://netlib.org/benchmark/performance.pdf